# Segmentation Fault from Fortran shared object

Tags: compilation, linker, fortran, shared-libraries, gfortran

I have a fortran subroutine in the file `gfunc.f90`. I want to call this subroutine from my main program in `test.f90`.

If I keep both files in the same directory and compile them with

`gfortran gfunc.f90 test.f90 -o test`

It works fine.

But I want the subroutine to be in a library. Thus, I create a subfolder called `gfunc/` and put `gfunc.f90` there. In that folder, I compile the module with

`gfortran -fdefault-real-8 -fPIC -c gfunc.f90`

and

`gfortran -fdefault-real-8 -shared -o gfunc.so gfunc.o`

I now compile the main program with

`gfortran test.f90 gfunc/gfunc.so`

But now I get a segmentation fault as soon as a variable in the subroutine is accessed.

How do I have to compile and link the library correctly?

Here, you find a minimal working example in order to reproduce the problem:

`gfunc.f90`:

```
module gfunc_module
implicit none
contains
subroutine gfunc(x, n, m, a, b, c)
    double precision, intent(in) :: x
    integer, intent(in) :: n, m
    double precision, dimension(n), intent(in) :: a
    double precision, dimension(m), intent(in) :: b
    double precision, dimension(n, m), intent(out) :: c
    integer :: i, j
    do j=1,m
        do i=1,n
             c(i,j) = exp(-x * (a(i)**2 + b(j)**2))
        end do
    end do
end subroutine
end module
```

`test.f90`:

```
program main

use gfunc_module

implicit none

integer, parameter :: dp = kind(1.0d0)

real(dp) :: x = 1.
integer, parameter :: n = 4
integer, parameter :: m = 4
real(dp), dimension(n) :: a = [-1., -0.33333333, .033333333, 1.]
real(dp), dimension(m) :: b = [-1., -0.33333333, .033333333, 1.]
real(dp), dimension(n, m) :: c

call gfunc(x, n, m, a, b, c)

write(*,*) c

end program main
```

Comment: Why do you have `-fdefault-real-8` and do things work without it?

Comment: Oh dear, thanks for pointing that out!! It never occurred to me, to check the floating point types. I just tried it without the argument and it works. I need that flag, because I actually want to call a third party library which is compiled with that flag. Do you want to answer the question or shall I just delete it, because of very low relevance to others?

Comment: Seen the comment from brady I think it is a relevant  question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should add `fdefault-real-8` to your compilation of test.f90:

```
gfortran -fdefault-real-8 test.f90 gfunc/gfunc.so
```

From the [documentation for gfortran](https://linux.die.net/man/1/gfortran) `-fdefault-real-8` is making `DOUBLE PRECISION` variables 16 bytes wide, so without it on test.f90 the double precision variables are only 8 bytes wide:

> **-fdefault-real-8**
>
> Set the default real type to an 8 byte wide type. Do nothing if this is already the default. This option also affects the kind of non-double real constants like 1.0, and does promote the default width of "DOUBLE PRECISION" to 16 bytes if possible, unless "-fdefault-double-8" is given, too.

Comment: Better is to write the code so you don't need to use compiler flags to change the precision of types - doing so is just asking for a life of pain, as you are learning here, and as fortran si good at this why not do it the standard way?

Comment: @brady, what does -default-real-8 actually do?  The answer may surprise if you read the gfortran source code.  As Ian says, it is best to avoid this option as it may have consequences that are difficult to debug.

Comment: @evets what does it actually do? Well, I'd refer you to the snippet from the documentation in my answer. If the implementation is different than as stated then I'd say the documentation is incomplete or there is a bug. I agree, it can be confusing, and relying on such flags is risky. But, that doesn't mean my answer isn't completely valid for the source code provided in the question.

Comment: @brady, I'm well aware of what the gfortran documentation states.  You did not answer my question where I purposefully wrote "what does it `actually` do?"  Read the gfortran source code.  The option does more than you think, and can break an application in wonderfully unexpected way.

Comment: @evets I intentionally did not answer your question. I'm not going to go dig through source code because you implied there might be something in there that will "surprise" me. My answer is relevant to the original question. If you think there is more information the OP should be aware of then by all means - write up your own answer.

Comment: @Ian Bush I'm actually using a third party library and in its manual it says emphatically that the library has to be compiled with that flag.

Comment: Oh dear. I'd complain to the authors, and/or find something better written. I really wish compilers didn't facilitate these things.